Is this function measurable?
Let $(X,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space and $(M,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ be the space of bounded real-valued sequences with the sup norm. Consider a sequence $\{\phi_n\}_n$ of $\mathcal{E}$-measurable uniformly bounded functions, and define $\varphi:X\rightarrow M$ as $\varphi(x):=(\phi_n(x))_n$. Is $\varphi$ measurable (with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology induced by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$)?
Probably there is a simple and clever way to see $\varphi$ as a composition of measurable functions, because I tried to use the definition of measurability and it seems impracticable.

In general, no. Let $X=\{0,1\}^\infty$, $\mathcal{E}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the product topology, and $\phi_n$ be the projection onto the $n$th factor. So $\phi$ is simply the identity.
It is well known that the cardinality of $\mathcal{E}$ is the cardinality of the continuum, which is also the cardinality of $X$. But every subset of $X$ is closed in the topology induced by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, so there would need to be at least as many measurable subsets of $X$ in $\mathcal{E}$ as there are subsets of the continuum, and there are not.
